# How to get diff between a branch on a modified master and a remote master?

Tags: git

What is the best way to "fork" a project, stay in touch with maintainers changes and develop your own features, while still being able to easily contribute back any of the features should they once be accepted?

Here is what I did, but encountered a problem.

I've cloned a repository, did some work in Feature1 branch, then merged changes from origin then from feature1, then origin...
Then I developed the feature2, which, of course, also contains the feature1 code.
The art below depicts the scenario (hopefully).

I have all the upstream changes in my master and develop on top of them. But, I cannot contribute back the Feature2, because it also contains the Feature1 code. What can I do? How to get feature2 patches against the 'aaa'?

Rebase Feature2 and cherry-pick to exclude Feature1 commits? Not much of a solution.

`git format-patch f2..f4` and then `git am`? All of the patches have to be applied manually!

```
          Feature1                                    Feature2
          a---b---c---d---e---f---g-----h---i         f2---f3---f4
         /                 \             \   \        /
    --------x'---y'---z'----1---o'---p'---2---3---q'-----r'---t'---l'---aaa'
     /     /    /    /        /    /             /      /    /    /
origin----x----y----z--------o----p-------------q------r----t----l---aaa
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to preserve the merge workflow depicted in the diagram.

```
git rebase --onto q Feature2
git checkout aaa
git merge Feature2
```

If I understand the diagram correctly, this would transform your local repository into something like this:

```
        Feature1
        a---b---c---d---e---f---g------h---i
       /                 \              \   \ 
      ------x'---y'---z'--1----o'---p'---2---3----aaa'
     /     /    /    /        /    /
origin----x----y----z--------o----p-------------q----r----t----l---aaa
                                                 \    \    \    \
                                                  \----r'---t'---l'---4---aaa''
                                                   \                 /
                                                    f2---f3---f4-----
                                                    Feature2
```

If Feature2 does not depend on any of the changes made in Feature1, that is all that you need to do.  If Feature2 does depend on some changes from Feature1, you'd have to cherry-pick those changes onto the Feature2 branch as well.

*Alternate solution*

Another approach would be to forget about all the merges, and rebase Feature2 directly onto the appropriate upstream commit (aaa).  You could do the same with Feature1, if you wanted.

```
git rebase --onto aaa Feature1
git rebase --onto aaa Feature2
```

Which would leave your local repository looking like this:

```
                               a---b---(...)---aaa'   Feature1
                              /
origin---x---(...)---t---l---aaa
                              \
                               f2---f3---f4---aaa''   Feature2
```

Again, this only works if Feature2 does not logically depend on Feature1. If it does, you will still have to cherry-pick those things from Feature1 onto Feature2.

Comment: Your solutions do not work because f2-f4 contain the code from Feature1. Changes are often in the same functions or even lines (for instance variable declarations or if conditions) so even cherry-picking has to be done manually for each commit.  It seems I need a way to do subtraction-like operation f2..f4 - a..i to get the clean patches out?!

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, you will have to manually tease out the logic of Feature2 from Feature1 in that case, no matter how you go about it.